# Logstash keep runing without crashing or output (windows as well as linux)

Tags: linux, windows, file, logstash

I am using a simple conf file to take in log4j file and output  as stdout (for debugging)

```
input { 
    file {
    type => "log4j"
    path => "C:\Stash\log4stash.log"
    start_position => "beginning"  } 
} 
output {# only for debug purpose
    stdout {
    codec => json 
    } 
}
```

When I run it in windows, sometime it spits out output on the console but mostly shows nothing after the following output:

> ←[33mUsing milestone 2 input plugin 'file'.    This plugin should be
>   stable, but if you see strange behavior, please let us know! For more
>   information on plugin milestones, see
>   http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/plugin-milestones {:level=>:warn}←[0m

Similar behavior on Linux too.
Any pointers?
Much Thanks.

Update: The conf file and the (logstash)debug log from linux.

```
input {
 file {
    type => "log4j"
    path => "/root/Downloads/log4stash.log"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}

output {
    # only for debug purposes   
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug 
    }
    elasticsearch_http {
        host => "<elastic.server>"
        port => 9200    
    }
}
```

From the log, it seems like logstash reads the file and process it and after registering and processing goes in wait state. But where is the stdout? and/or nothing in elastic search (query using kibana UI).
Much Thanks, again, for your input.

```
    [root@cdh-cc3 logstash-1.4.2]# bin/logstash -f /root/Downloads/ll4j-2.conf --debug

Reading config file {:file=>"logstash/agent.rb", :level=>:debug, :line=>"301"}
Compiled pipeline code:
@inputs = []
@filters = []
@outputs = []
@input_file_1 = plugin("input", "file", LogStash::Util.hash_merge_many({ "type" => ("log4j".force_encoding("UTF-8")) }, { "path" => ("/root/Downloads/log4stash.log".force_encoding("UTF-8")) }, { "start_position" => ("beginning".force_encoding("UTF-8")) }))

@inputs << @input_file_1
@output_stdout_2 = plugin("output", "stdout", LogStash::Util.hash_merge_many({ "codec" => ("json".force_encoding("UTF-8")) }))

@outputs << @output_stdout_2
@output_elasticsearch_http_3 = plugin("output", "elasticsearch_http", LogStash::Util.hash_merge_many({ "host" => ("elastic.search".force_encoding("UTF-8")) }, { "port" => 9200 }))

@outputs << @output_elasticsearch_http_3
  @filter_func = lambda do |event, &block|
    extra_events = []
    @logger.debug? && @logger.debug("filter received", :event => event.to_hash)
    extra_events.each(&block)
  end
  @output_func = lambda do |event, &block|
    @logger.debug? && @logger.debug("output received", :event => event.to_hash)
    @output_stdout_2.handle(event)
    @output_elasticsearch_http_3.handle(event)

  end {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/pipeline.rb", :line=>"26"}
Using milestone 2 input plugin 'file'. This plugin should be stable, but if you see strange behavior, please let us know! For more information on plugin milestones, see http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/plugin-milestones {:level=>:warn, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"209"}
config LogStash::Codecs::Plain/@charset = "UTF-8" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"105"}
config LogStash::Inputs::File/@type = "log4j" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"105"}
config LogStash::Inputs::File/@path = ["/root/Downloads/log4stash.log"] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"105"}
config LogStash::Inputs::File/@start_position = "beginning" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"105"}
config LogStash::Inputs::File/@debug = false {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"105"}
config LogStash::Inputs::File/@codec = <LogStash::Codecs::Plain charset=>"UTF-8"> {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"105"}
config LogStash::Inputs::File/@add_field = {} {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"105"}
config LogStash::Inputs::File/@stat_interval = 1 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"105"}
config LogStash::Inputs::File/@discover_interval = 15 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"105"}
config LogStash::Inputs::File/@sincedb_write_interval = 15 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"105"}
config LogStash::Codecs::JSON/@charset = "UTF-8" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"105"}
config LogStash::Outputs::Stdout/@codec = <LogStash::Codecs::JSON charset=>"UTF-8"> {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"105"}
config LogStash::Outputs::Stdout/@type = "" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"105"}
config LogStash::Outputs::Stdout/@tags = [] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"105"}
config LogStash::Outputs::Stdout/@exclude_tags = [] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"105"}
config LogStash::Outputs::Stdout/@workers = 1 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"105"}
Using milestone 2 output plugin 'elasticsearch_http'. This plugin should be stable, but if you see strange behavior, please let us know! For more information on plugin milestones, see http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/plugin-milestones {:level=>:warn, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"209"}
config LogStash::Codecs::Plain/@charset = "UTF-8" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"105"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearchHTTP/@host = "elastic.search" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"105"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearchHTTP/@port = 9200 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"105"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearchHTTP/@type = "" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"105"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearchHTTP/@tags = [] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"105"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearchHTTP/@exclude_tags = [] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"105"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearchHTTP/@codec = <LogStash::Codecs::Plain charset=>"UTF-8"> {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"105"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearchHTTP/@workers = 1 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"105"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearchHTTP/@index = "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"105"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearchHTTP/@manage_template = true {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"105"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearchHTTP/@template_name = "logstash" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"105"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearchHTTP/@template_overwrite = false {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"105"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearchHTTP/@user = nil {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"105"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearchHTTP/@password = <password> {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"105"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearchHTTP/@flush_size = 100 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"105"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearchHTTP/@idle_flush_time = 1 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"105"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearchHTTP/@document_id = nil {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"105"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearchHTTP/@replication = "sync" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"105"}
Registering file input {:path=>["/root/Downloads/log4stash.log"], :level=>:info, :file=>"logstash/inputs/file.rb", :line=>"74"}
No sincedb_path set, generating one based on the file path {:sincedb_path=>"/root/.sincedb_624f220c3c6db2a30932d4fb6e93769d", :path=>["/root/Downloads/log4stash.log"], :level=>:info, :file=>"logstash/inputs/file.rb", :line=>"115"}
Pipeline started {:level=>:info, :file=>"logstash/pipeline.rb", :line=>"78"}
_sincedb_open: reading from /root/.sincedb_624f220c3c6db2a30932d4fb6e93769d {:level=>:debug, :file=>"filewatch/tail.rb", :line=>"199"}
_sincedb_open: setting [1451032, 0, 64768] to 1206 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"filewatch/tail.rb", :line=>"203"}
_discover_file_glob: /root/Downloads/log4stash.log: glob is: ["/root/Downloads/log4stash.log"] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"filewatch/watch.rb", :line=>"117"}
_discover_file: /root/Downloads/log4stash.log: new: /root/Downloads/log4stash.log (exclude is []) {:level=>:debug, :file=>"filewatch/watch.rb", :line=>"126"}
_open_file: /root/Downloads/log4stash.log: opening {:level=>:debug, :file=>"filewatch/tail.rb", :line=>"98"}
/root/Downloads/log4stash.log: sincedb last value 1206, cur size 1206 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"filewatch/tail.rb", :line=>"122"}
/root/Downloads/log4stash.log: sincedb: seeking to 1206 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"filewatch/tail.rb", :line=>"124"}
writing sincedb (delta since last write = 1423673806) {:level=>:debug, :file=>"filewatch/tail.rb", :line=>"177"}
/root/Downloads/log4stash.log: file grew, old size 0, new size 1206 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"filewatch/watch.rb", :line=>"81"}
Automatic template management enabled {:manage_template=>"true", :level=>:info, :file=>"logstash/outputs/elasticsearch_http.rb", :line=>"104"}
Template Search URL: {:template_search_url=>"http://elastic.search:9200/_template/*", :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/outputs/elasticsearch_http.rb", :line=>"112"}
_discover_file_glob: /root/Downloads/log4stash.log: glob is: ["/root/Downloads/log4stash.log"] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"filewatch/watch.rb", :line=>"117"}
_discover_file_glob: /root/Downloads/log4stash.log: glob is: ["/root/Downloads/log4stash.log"] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"filewatch/watch.rb", :line=>"117"}
_discover_file_glob: /root/Downloads/log4stash.log: glob is: ["/root/Downloads/log4stash.log"] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"filewatch/watch.rb", :line=>"117"}
```

Comment: Is anything being written to the log file?

Comment: Please provide the log sample and output.

Comment: Where can I fing logstash logs? I am running logstash directly from command line (windows 8) and terminal (linux).
The output is: 
C:\logstash-1.4.2>bin\logstash agent -f C:/Stash/ll4j-2.conf
←[33mUsing milestone 2 input plugin 'file'. This plugin should be stable, but if you see strange behavior, please let us know! For
 more information on plugin milestones, see http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/plugin-milestones {:level=>:warn}←[0m

Comment: The sample log (log4j) file mentioned in conf file:

2015-02-06 11:43:06,844  INFO   [SubLoggger] This is a log message 
2015-02-06 11:43:06,851  INFO   [SubLoggger] {"some-date":"Fri Feb 06 11:43:06 PST 2015","some-key":"key-data","customer":"customer"}

Comment: You might check if you have a sincedb file that's recorded a position for your input file.

Comment: @rutter thanks. sincedb has following contents:
1451032 0 64768 1206
which incidentally matches with the following line from aforementioned log:

Answer (score 2):

Thanks all.
Found out what was going on. I found that logstash “remembers” the file it has parsed. So first time the log files I sent to logstash I did dry run and didn’t send them to elastic. Since that run, logstash weren’t parsing the same files. Removed the sincedb files and that make logstash to parse them again (tried it on linux).
Lesson learned:-)